# Debian wheezy, update repository

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy

I'm working with a `Debian GNU/Linux 7.5 (wheezy)`

When I check the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` The file has this line:

```
# Line commented out by installer because it failed to verify:
#deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
```

I tried to replaces for another repo line, but each time I replace it and run the command `apt-get update` after a while, I get:

```
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debian wheezy is no longer supported. It is *two* major releases older than stable. It has not received any updates since [31 May 2018](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS).

The resolution is to dist-upgrade to oldstable, or to stable.

Answer (score 9):

You can still use the archive repository but there is no more updates:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian wheezy main
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian-security/ wheezy updates/main
```